# Dropdown Navigation with Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, navigation

I have been going nuts trying to find a jquery slider to achieve something similiar to the effect found [here](http://toyota.com) (if you click select vehicle you get a dropdown that slides left or right with vehicles).  Does anyone know of a jquery plugin to achieve this?

I have used many slider plugins over the past, but it seems like they were really made for images (slideshows) and not to be used for navigation purposes. It doesnt need to drop down, I just need to cycle through sections once a tab is clicked.

I guess I should clarify a bit more on this:

**I guess it is primarily a couple tabs I need which would scroll through content underneath (based on which tab was clicked)**

Answer (score 0):

I was working last 2 days on same problem and here is my solution:

```
<style>
.horizontalni {
    border:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 4px rgba(125,125,125,0.1);
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    max-width:800px;
    background:silver;
    overflow:hidden;

}

/* navigation items */
.horizontalni .navigation {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    display:block;
    font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:3em;
    height:55px;
    padding-top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 0 0 2px;
    width:50px;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s;
    transition:all 0.4s;
}

.horizontalni:hover .navigation {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 0 0 2px;
}

.horizontalni .navigation:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.horizontalni .previous {
    left:0;
}

.horizontalni .next {
    right:0;
}

/* carousel container */
.horizontalni ul {
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -o-box-orient:horizontal;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-ms-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-o-box;
    display:box;

    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding:0;

}

/* standard width and height for the carousel items */
.horizontalni li {
    border:solid 1px #333;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:150px;
    max-width:300px;
}

/* animation properties for the carousel */
.animate ul {
    -moz-transition:margin 1s;
    -ms-transition:margin 1s;
    -webkit-transition:margin 1s;
    -o-transition:margin 1s;
    transition:margin 1s;
}

/* different color for each of our items */
.horizontalni li {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  background: #4a4a4a url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8a8a8a), color-stop(50%, #707070), color-stop(51%, #626262), color-stop(100%, #787878));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  text-align: center;
}
.horizontalni a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #333333;
}

.horizontalni > ul > li a {
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  filter: none;
}

.horizontalni > ul > li:hover {
  background: #8a8a8a url(images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(50%, #4a4a4a), color-stop(51%, #3b3b3b), color-stop(100%, #525252));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}


.horizontalni .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
    z-index:1;

}
.horizontalni .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  IE7

  *width: 100%;
}
.horizontalni .has-sub ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
.horizontalni .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:1;
}

.has-sub.parent .wrapper {
    position: fixed;
}
</style>
<div id="carousel" class="horizontalni wrapper">
            <a href="" class="navigation previous">&laquo;</a>
            <a href="" class="navigation next">&raquo;</a>
            <ul>
                <li ><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
                <li ><a>Test2</a></li>
                <li><a>Test3</a></li>
                <li ><a>Test4</a></li>
                <li ><a>Test5</a></li>
                <li class="has-sub parent"><a>Test6</a>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a>Test61</a></li>
                            <li><a>Test62</a></li>
                            <li><a>Test63</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="child-element"><a>Test7</a></li>
                <li class="child-element"><a>Test8</a></li>
                <li class="child-element"><a>Test9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="http://www.andismith.com/flexbox-carousel/library/js/modernizr.js"></script>   
        <script src="http://www.andismith.com/flexbox-carousel/library/js/common.js"></script>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pg6wsfsr/9/)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, not quite what I was looking for for this issue, but it actually helped out on something else I was working on.

Comment: Sorry I just now saw link that you posted and just saw that this is not what you needed.

Comment: No worries at all. I appreciate the quick response though.